# SwiftUI NavigationView nested bar issue

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a View with a list with navigationLinks, and show a list of items to DetailView, and DetailView can go to another View and so on. Therefore it will have a full navigation stack in here.

However, in our app, we have two ways to show this view, first, a presenting View to show this view. Second, by other navigationLink under another NavigationView to push to this view. In the first case, it is fine. however in second case, it will show nested navigation bar, which I don't really like it.

Is there any possible way to show the following view without any nested navigationBar, in the pushing and presenting(UIKit wording) way

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(items) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item)) {
                   ItemRow(item)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Item list")
        }
    }
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: Just separate this view on two: one with list only and second navigation view containing that first one.

Comment: @Asperi let's say this view is separated in another pod, the caller doesn't know too much about the view. in my view , how to detect if its parent view push it or present it? or another word , how to know the parent view has NavigationView already?

Comment: In "DetailView" do you have a NavigationView? If yes, then, remove it because that could be the issue. There must only be one NavigationView per stack.

Answer (score 0):

As Asperi says, you must separate the `View` into two `Views`. You have double `NavigationBar` because in the case where you already enter with the previous `NavigationView` at the top level of the `View` hierarchy, having another `NavigatioView` makes it double the `NavigationBar`.

You must do something like this in the `View` before this one:

```
var body: some View {

    VSTack {
      Text("Hello Word")

      Button(action: {
        if isShowWithPresent { // Some Bool
           NavigationView {
             SomeView()
           }
        } else {
          AnotherView() // Some View without the NavigationView in the code
        }
      }) {
         Text("Hit Me!")
      }
    }
 }
```